# Минимальный код для загрузки файла в джанго

Tags: python, django

Есть такое представление

```
class MyView(FormView):
    template_name = 'app_my/some.html'
    form_class = FileForm
    success_url = '/'
```

Вот шаблон

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div>
        {% for f in form %}
        <div>{{ f }}</div>
        {% endfor %}
        <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Ну, и форма

```
class FileForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    file = forms.FileField()
```

При нажатии на кнопку отправить предполагаю, что должен перейти на главную страницу, но вылетает страница недоступна. В чем причина?

Comment: Прям так и пишет "страница недоступна", без подробностей, без логов ошибок?

Comment: вот, что пишет "Страница недоступна Если проблема не исчезнет, свяжитесь с владельцем сайта.
HTTP ERROR 405"

Comment: Ошибка 405 означает, что запрос отправлен с неправильным методом (вы отправляете POST, а представление или какой-то промежуточный сервер видимо согласны принимать только GET)

Comment: спасибо, да, в этом ошибка

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас все же не "страница недоступна" а "страница не найдена", то попробуйте
`success_url = ''`, без слэша.